# Visual Studio Redraw Fail

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ide, devenv

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to develop SQL Server 2008 R2 SSIS packages. Whenever I switch between applications, the components in the package lose their outlines, break point visual markers - it just looks ugly.

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img72/5696/visualstudioredrawfail.jpg](http://a.imageshack.us/img72/5696/visualstudioredrawfail.jpg)

Here is where everything except the name and the background color is lost

[alt text http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/9826/visualstudioredrawfail2.jpg](http://img828.imageshack.us/img828/9826/visualstudioredrawfail2.jpg)

I have uninstalled an reinstalled Visual Studio several times so far but no luck.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, you are using an onboard video card?

I had exactly the same issue.

Upgraded to el cheapo Nvidia card, no problem any more.

Note: this only happened in VS for me, no other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Stop Table PC Input Service. Disable it.
It stopped all refresh issues on my Intel I7 Windows 7 64 bit machine using AMD Radeon 6450 adapter.